# How to pass a BLE characteristic to another class or use 2 layout files for 1 java class

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

My DeviceControlActivity class uses the gatt_services_characterisitcs.xml
From here, i can send data fine using the bluetoothgattHM_10 characteristic i have made.
My MainActivity Class uses the activity_main.xml layout.

From MainActivity the characteristic returns null, essentially it doesn't carry its value over. I have tried instances instanceOfClass.bluetoothgattHM_10 and it recognises the variable, but returns null, which i need to fix. 
The other idea i had, was inlude my MainActivity class code in DeviceControlActivity, gets around the scope issue, but i cant seem to have 2 layouts running of the same class. I have tried ViewFlipper, Broke my code very badly, setContent() Didnt play ball, so i tried making the elements invisiable, using the setVisibility(view.GONE) command, and it has no effect on the element. no errors either, and the line of code is ran. Any ideas would be helpfull!

Comment: For that you have to use service class.

Comment: Check this https://github.com/twang2218/sensortag-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/ti/ble/common/BluetoothLeService.java

Comment: I have read through the github link, dont understand what i am meant to be looking at though?

Comment: You don't have to use a service, u can do this in the Application class or use a static bluetooth manager class. Just make sure to pass the application context. Then use broadcasts or callbacks to feed information.